# ML Kit text recognition: How to get text based on position in image?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm making an app for myself to scan receipts, and put the data in a database. I tried using ML kit text recognition, and it works pretty well. However I'm having problems extracting the data from the recognized text. I'll explain with an example:

This is the format of the receipt, which is how I want to get the data:

```
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| Amount |  Name  | Price | Total |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 | Cheese |       | 1,15  |
|      1 | Eggs   |       | 2,59  |
|      2 | Milk   | 0,99  | 1,98  |
|      1 | Butter |       | 0,80  |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

However when running the text recognition, it formats the data in really weird ways. For example the above receipt would give these blocks:

```
Amount
Price
Name Cheese Eggs Milk 0,99
Butter
Total 1,15 2,59
1,98 0,80
```

It seems to skip the single numbers in the amount column, but I can work around that. However I can't figure out how to parse above data into the data I want, especially connecting the prices to the names. Is there a way to change the blocks so that it takes only the rows or columns of the receipt, instead of this randomness?

Edit: when using lines or elements instead of blocks, I get the following result:

```
Amount
Price
Name
Cheese
Eggs
Milk
0,99
Butter
Total
1,15
2,59
1,98
0,80
```

However I still have the same problem: how do I pair the items with the correct prices?

Comment: There are three level of text result you can get - blocks, lines, and elements (in increasing granularity) - which level are you using? See https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android#4.-extract-text-from-blocks-of-recognized-text

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As described in the post, the result I posted are blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using lines or elements instead of blocks in that case (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android#4.-extract-text-from-blocks-of-recognized-text) and then use the position of those blocks to reconstruct the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that, however I still have the same problem: how do I pair the items with the correct price?

Comment: You will need to do your own association according to the text box coordinate using either `element.cornerPoints` or `element.boundingBox`

Answer (score 1):

you can pair elements using line.boundingBox.top value. if line has the same approximate value from top, then you can count it as the same row. here is the example of code:

```
val tolerance = 5
 val rows: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf()

    for(block in blocks) {
        for(line in block.lines){
            val topValue = line.boundingBox?.top ?: continue

            var foundRow: MutableList<String>? = null
            for((rowTop,rowTexts) in rows){
                if(abs(rowTop - topValue) <= tolerance){
                    foundRow = rowTexts
                    break
                }
            }

            if(foundRow == null){
                foundRow = mutableListOf()
                rows[topValue] = foundRow
            }

            foundRow.add(line.text)
        }
    }
```